# Unable to start process from powershell

Tags: windows-services

Folks

I am trying to invoke a batch script from a power shell file and the invocation works fine if executed manually.

```
   Start-Process C:\USR\test.bat
```

However i created a service in C# which is able to delete and write logs using the powershell script however it simply ignores this step and nothing happens. Is it because this script is invoked by a windows service ?

```
if (Test-Path \\xxxsharepathfullper\FileWatcher\target\watcher.mon) {
echo "File removed" >> C:\USR\logger.txt
Start-Process C:\USR\test.bat
Remove-Item \\xxxsharepathfullper\FileWatcher\target\watcher.mon
}
else {

}
```

- Execution policy is unrestricted

Answer (score 1):

Check access rights on a share, maybe your admin user don't have rights to access it.

Comment: Just in case - "admin user" here is that under which you run your service, it may not be default Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try run the process as administrator and log any error:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\USR\test.bat" -RedirectStandardError "testError.txt" -verb RunAs
```